# Listview setCellFactory with generic label

Tags: java, javafx

I try do create a customize item within `ListView`, let's say it's label and I want to execute `setCellFactory`, while I'm using `Label` I don't see the item (the text of the label), why?

```
ListView<Label> list = new ListView<Label>();
ObservableList<Label> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Label("123"), new Label("45678999"));

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox box = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("ListViewExample");
    box.getChildren().addAll(list);
    VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);

    list.setItems(data);

    list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Label>, ListCell<Label>>() {


            @Override 
            public ListCell<Label> call(ListView<Label> list) {
                ListCell<Label> cell = new ListCell<Label>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setItem(item);
                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }
        }
    );

    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do want to show items extending `Node` there is no need to use custom `ListCell`s. The `ListCell`s of the default factory are doing this already.

However in your case you're calling `setItem` instead of `setGraphic` and also you do not set the property back to `null`, when the cell becomes empty:

```
list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Label>, ListCell<Label>>() {

    @Override
    public ListCell<Label> call(ListView<Label> list) {
        ListCell<Label> cell = new ListCell<Label>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                // also sets to graphic to null when the cell becomes empty
                setGraphic(item);
            }
        };

        return cell;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) I missed setGraphic